# Integrate Microsoft OneDrive for Business with Community Cloud?

Tags: community-cloud

I want to provide my Salesforce Contacts with access to PDF files stored on Microsoft OneDrive for Business through Salesforce Community Cloud.

There is guidance on how to do this for internal Chatter use, but I'm not sure that it would work for Community Cloud:

http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring15/release-notes/rn_chatter_files_connect_onedr.htm

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using SF Files Connect to get access to an external Data source, you might be able to use ContentDocument and ContentDocumentLink standard objects to share data to your respective communities.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm